# how to generate unicode strings only with multi-byte characters

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

How does one generate a UTF-8 character sequence where each character is represented by multiple bytes, and each character is chosen from the set of all characters with multi-byte presentations?

I'm trying to test how my application handles UTF-8 with multi-byte characters.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I have to ask: what are *multi-byte* characters? Anything outside the Latin-1 range? Or are you talking about multiple UTF-8 bytes? Or UTF-16 code units perhaps? Not that your question is on-topic.

Comment: I meant a UTF-8 character sequence, where each character is represented by multiple bytes.  Sorry if this was off-topic.  I searched for a module online to do this, but couldn't find one.  I rephrased the question.

Comment: That covers everything outside of the ASCII range, so codepoints U+0080 through to `sys.maxunicode`. Why not just use the `random` module to produce those directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything outside the ASCII range (U+0000 - U+007F) gives you a Unicode character that encodes to multiple UTF-8 bytes.

Just randomly generate those:

```
import sys
import random

def random_nonascii_unicode(length):
    return u''.join(unichr(random.randint(0x80, sys.maxunicode)) for _ in range(length))
```

and encode to UTF-8 as needed:

```
>>> random_nonascii_unicode(10)
u'\ue82a\u62ac\ufe97\u97a3\u02c5\u4955\u1ad8\u9cf7\u8cba\u62e7'
>>> random_nonascii_unicode(10).encode('utf8')
'\xe3\x98\xb8\xe6\x91\x84\xe9\x99\xab\xeb\xb3\x8d\xef\xb7\x91\xe9\x9e\x9f\xe9\x99\xb8\xee\x9a\x9d\xec\x86\x87\xed\xa1\xb0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Martijn.